# Method (rev=false) relationship to if statement and puts

Tags: ruby, methods, function

I'm working through the Ruby tutorials on Codeacademy and i'm struggling to understand the method parameter `rev=false` in relation to the if/else statement. **I know how it works but not why it works**. The Codeacademy description is confusing me which is why i'm posting here.

Why does this print in reverse? `puts "Z-A: #{alphabetize(books, true)}"`
What's its relationship with `rev=false)`?

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
        if rev
            arr.sort { |firstItem, secondItem|            
            secondItem <=> firstItem }
        else
           arr.sort { |firstItem, secondItem|            
           firstItem <=> secondItem }

        end
    end

    books = ["Heart of Darkness", "Code Complete", "The Lorax", "The Prophet", "Absalom, Absalom!"]

    puts "A-Z: #{(books)}"
    puts "Z-A: #{alphabetize(books, true)}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort order is reversed:

```
secondItem <=> firstItem
```

vs:

```
firstItem <=> secondItem
```

`rev = false` sets a default value, i.e. if you don't pass a second argument, `rev` is set to `false`.

This could have been written as:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  if rev
    arr.sort.reverse
  else
    arr.sort
  end
end
```

Comment: does the `true` in `puts "Z-A: #{alphabetize(books, true)}"` apply to the `rev` ?

Comment: Exactly, it sets `arr` to `books` and `rev` to `true`.

Comment: Ok, i see. Do you think the exercise is for demonstration purpose? It seems convoluted to go about that way or that the simplest code to use?

Comment: I've added a simpler implementation to my answer